# which flame starting point (game or base_game) for point and click 2D static type adventure game?

Tags: flame

Looking for points/advice re using Flame (Flutter library) for a point & click 2D adventure game.  So mainly different rooms with images, tap listeners, some minimal animations.  So no physics or "real time" stuff.

Q1 - Which of the flame starting points would be recommended re "game.dart" vs "base_game.dart"?

Q2 - Any other tips/guidance for this?  (e.g. dont' bother using flame just use flutter?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very wide question for the StackOverflow format, but since I'm one of the developers of Flame I'll try to respond as well as I can.

Q1:

- Definitely go with `BaseGame`, if you are using `Game` you get locked out of a lot of the features of the engine. `Game` is used if you pretty much only need the game loop.
- Make use of the components, they will make your
  development process a lot simpler. For examples use `SpriteComponent`
  instead of `Sprite` directly etc.
- There is also a package built on top of Flame that is called Bonfire (not built by the flame-engine team) that you could use too, but that is a more opinionated way for writing an RPG game.

Q2:

- You can join our [Discord](https://discord.com/invite/pxrBmy4) chat and we'll try to answer any questions you have.
- Use `v1.0.0-rcX`, even though it is still rc it is the definitely the way to go if you are starting a new project now, so that you don't have to migrate it later. In a couple of months the final `v1.0.0` should be released.
- Have a look in the [examples directory](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/tree/master/doc/examples) in the repository, you can get inspiration for how to use most features available in the engine there.

Comment: excellent thanks - so if going with BaseGame/flame I wouldn't need I assume to continue learning flutter_bloc and hydrated_bloc for state management?   (that's been my current challenge working out bloc, then trying to work out after a change in game location how to trigger an async image load for the next set of images before then passing onto my CustomPainter/canvas..

Comment: I haven't heard anyone using `flutter_bloc` or `hydrated_bloc` with Flame, and I haven't used them myself, but I would assume that they are more on a Flutter widget level and Flame is just widget and most of your game happens within that Widget (you can have overlays etc with normal flutter widgets too). Not sure I understood the last part of your question.